# How to deal with arrays of static objects?

Tags: java, arrays, static

I'm having an issue dealing with static object types in a parser I'm writing.

```
glob = new func("glob");
glob.addChild(new func("wrong"));
System.out.println(glob.name);
```

func is a static class that I'm referencing in the above code within main. When this code is run, the printed text is "wrong". I'm assuming that making func static as I did is causing there to only ever be one func allowed, and it's being overwritten since I can't create instances of func. Is there a way around this? Here's part of the code for the declaration of func for reference

```
static class func{
  public func (String name){
     //etc
  }
}
```

This is becoming an issue because I  want to be able to create a nest of these objects to use for determining scope within a parser. func would have children, and the idea was that a child node could look for a 'variable' (here just a string) that I add first within itself, then within its parent, and so on down the line. Creating children just overwrited the parent though.

Update: People wanted more code from func

```
static class func{
public static func[] children;
public String name;
public static func parent;
private static int child_index, var_index;
private static String[][] vars;
    public func (String name, func parent){
       children = new func[50];
       //etc
    }
 }
```

You're right that I did have a static name. If I remove that, my worry is that the vars/children arrays will still continue to be overwritten, and removing those gives me a lot of 'non-static variables cannot be referenced...' messages.

Comment: `I'm assuming that making func static as I did is causing there to only ever be one func allowed` - nope, `static` inner classes don't have a special relationship to their enclosing class, that's all. Classes are always "static" (one class "instance" per classloader) and `static` doesn't prevent you from creating instances, that would be done differently. Since `static` is only allowed on inner classes, there seems to be an outer class, which might cause the problem. Can you post that?

Comment: Please include all the code for the `func` class.  The only way what you describe could happen is if the `name` argument in the constructor is assigned to a static field `name`

Comment: Btw, where are the _arrays_ you're mentioning in the title?

Comment: @NickHolt I've updated my op to contain more of the class. You were right on your static name field, but any insight into how to deal with the other static fields? I'm using these objects within jflex, and it requires me to be able to work in static classes. I guess my question is, can I access non-static methods from within my subclass in static places?

Comment: @Skyl3lazer just make all the fields non-`static`, just because a class is static, doesn't mean its fields need to be.

Comment: The member functions of func were static, and thus were causing errors if the variables weren't. I figured those had to be static because func was, but apparently not. Thanks, this fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `static` modifier on a class doesn't do the same thing as `static` on other entities.  First of all, you can't apply `static` to a top-level class at all.  It's only useful for a class defined inside another class:

```
public class Outer {

    public class Inner {
    ...
    }

    static public class Nested {
    ...
    }

}
```

The difference is that whenever you create an object of class `Inner`, the object "belongs", in a sense, to some object of an `Outer` class.  The `Inner` object contains a reference to some `Outer` object, and its methods can reference fields of the `Outer` object to which it belongs.

The `Nested` class, however, is more like a top-level class; the main difference is that outside classes can refer to it as `Outer.Nested`, which can be useful when you want several different nested classes all named `Nested`.  It's a way to avoid "polluting the namespace" with top-level class names, and to make it clear that a `Nested` is somehow closely related to an `Outer`.  Also, because of Java's rules about visibility, a `Nested` class's methods can access `private` members of `Outer`, which an outside top-level class can't do.

But it doesn't mean you can create only one `Nested`.  If you want a class that can have only one object, use a singleton pattern.  (But also think about whether you really want to do this and why; singleton patterns are disdained by some programmers, probably because they look too much like global variables, which reduces the flexibility to make certain kinds of changes to your program in the future.)  (P.S. After trying to read your question more carefully, I'm not sure that a singleton is what you want, and in fact I'm not clear at all on what your design is supposed to look like.)

Answer (score 0):

It is meant to be so, since a static variable is a variable owned by a `Class` and not instances of that Class and it is so for inner static classes.

Otherwise I can't see how did you manage to make your `func` class static since as far as I know Java do not allow Top-level classes to be static and only inner classes can be so.

I can't see clearely what you are aiming to achieve but you should reconsider your design. Maybe with better explanation someone could bring some help.